# Could we please have an Affable Geek Memorial Chat Room?

Tags: discussion, chat

Could we please have an Affable Geek Memorial Chat Room?

I feel like I need it.

I only knew the guy through Christianity.SE, yet here I am,  mourning his death.

In life, he probably didn't even respect me as a top Christianity.SE contributor, but I really respected him. Now he is gone. Hopefully to Heaven.

R.I.P. Affable Geek.

[image: Affable Geek]

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate less because it is and more because with this chat room created, I think any future answers would be better posted under [the Memorial post](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4496/30) and comments can be taken to the room as appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just created it.

[Affable Geek Memorial](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21424/affable-geek-memorial)